# Unable to give draw balloon on DWG file using Autodesk Viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autocad, dwg, autodesk-construction-cloud

We are attempting to create a balloon on a DWG file but are unsure how to do so in Autodesk Viewer. Could you possibly offer a solution or do you have any resources for this in the Autodesk team?

Also, how to get callout API on the normal Autodesk Viewer?

[We are referring circle as a balloons which consists of numbers!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gkHdz.png)

We implemented callouts in Autodesk Construction Cloud, but we couldn't find a way to convert a rectangle of callouts to a circle (Balloons).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, when we're viewing a drawing with Viewer, we're actually viewing a non-modifieble translation of the original desing.

You can find the detailed process at https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/tutorials/prep-file4viewer/

From there, you have two options:

1. Modify the source file and prepare the new version for Viewer
2. Add the ballon and callouts to the model scene

For option 1 you'll need to use Design Automation API for AutoCAD.
You can refer to the [documentation](https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/design-automation/v3/tutorials/autocad/)

For option 2 you can add [SVG](https://aps.autodesk.com/blog/add-svg-your-2d-sheets-forge-viewer) to the scene, take advantage [markupcore](https://aps.autodesk.com/blog/using-autodeskviewingmarkupscore-extension) extensions or integrate your [custom markup](https://aps.autodesk.com/blog/placing-custom-markup-dbid)